# MySQL DB & PHP - Select Query not working with PHP but works in MySQL WorkBench

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to query MySQL db through PHP script.

```
SELECT i.id issues_id, i.project_id, i.tracker_id, t.name tracker_name, i.subject,  
       i.author_id, i.assigned_to_id, u1.firstname tfirst, u1.lastname tlast, 
       u2.firstname dfirst, u2.lastname dlast, i.updated_on, cast(i.updated_on as DATE)
       updated_date, ist.name istatusname, concat(u1.lastname, ', ', u1.firstname) Tname, 
       concat(u2.lastname, ', ', u2.firstname) Dname
FROM issues i, trackers t, users u1, users u2, issue_statuses ist
WHERE i.tracker_id = t.id AND 
      i.author_id = u1.id AND 
      i.assigned_to_id = u2.id AND 
      ist.id = i.status_id AND 
      concat(u1.lastname, ', ', u1.firstname) like '%' AND 
      concat(u2.lastname, ', ', u2.firstname) like '%' AND 
      t.name like '%' AND 
      ist.name like '%' AND 
      cast(i.updated_on as DATE) BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2015-01-01';
```

This works perfectly fine when I run the sql code in MySQL WorkBench.
However, when I try to run this through PHP, I get zero results.

The problem seems to stem from the line:

```
ist.name like '%'
```

When I omit this part of the code, it runs as expected in both MySQL WorkBench and through PHP script (Including trying other values within the quotation marks).
Adding that portion, no matter what I put as the value, gives me zero results through PHP script.

---

By popular demand,
Pertinent PHP CODE:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
--SQL CODE HERE--
");
```

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<td>' . $row['issues_id'] . '</td>';
--ECHO COLUMNS HERE--
}
```

---

What is the problem???

Comment: Since the problem lies in the PHP part, why did you not show any of this code?

Comment: because i have run the script in PHP without that one line and it works as expected, and i have run other SQL through the same PHP script and it worked as expected?  
does that mean the PHP portion could still be wrong?

Comment: Yes. The PHP could still be wrong.

Comment: Is that enough PHP?
Anything in particular that you are looking for?
An explanation on your train of thought would be helpful for me to be able to help you help me. Thanks

Comment: Most likely it's because you're using "" for the SQL query in PHP and you didn't escape the % character.

Comment: then in that case, None of my other SQL queries would/should have worked. Also, it does not require any escape characters when i use single quotes as shown in my question's SELECT statement